# cubepoints/buddypress show new rank on activity?

Tags: buddypress, cubepoints

i wanted to display on each user's profile activity stream the rank they have unlocked and which will be shown in the activity streams

for example on the activity

- user1 has unlocked level 2
- user4 has unlocked level 4
- user1 has changed there avatar

[image: img]

Comment: well i have not tried anything i just made the photo using photoshop thats all, thats why im asking for some help?.. im no coder myself but i understand a bit but when it comes to starting from scratch i find it difficult so thats my lack of experience